# in django admin, can we have a multiple select based on choices

Tags: django, django-admin

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices

i've read through the documentation and this implies using a database table for dynamic data, however it states

> choices is meant for static data that doesn't change much, if ever.

so what if i want to use choices, but have it select multiple because the data i'm using is quite static, e.g days of the week.

is there anyway to achieve this without a database table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ChoiceField is not really suitable for multiple choices, instead I would use a [ManyToManyField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField).  Ignore the fact that Choices can be used instead of ForeignKey for static data for now.  If it turns out to be a performance issue, there are ways to represent this differently (one being a binary mask approach), but they require way more work.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

1) create a Form class and set an attribute to provide your static choices to a MultipleChoiceField

> ```
> from django import forms
> from myapp.models import MyModel, MYCHOICES
>
> class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
>     myfield = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=MYCHOICES, widget=forms.SelectMultiple)
>     class Meta:
>         model = MyModel
> ```

2) then, if you're using the admin interface, set the form attribute in your admin class so tit will use your customized form

> ```
> from myapp.models import MyModel
> from myapp.forms import MyForm
> from django.contrib import admin
>
> class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     form = MyForm
>
> admin.site.register(MyModel, MyAdmin)
> ```

Comment: But how is `myfield` defined in `MyModel`, and how is it mapped on DB?

Answer (score 1):

Try following configuration. In `models.py`

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_choices = models.TextField(help_text="It's a good manners to write it")
```

in `forms.py`

```
CHOICES = ((1,1), (2,2))
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_choices = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # maybe you can set initial with self.fields['my_choices'].initial = initial 
        # but it doesn't work wity dynamic choices
        obj = kwargs.get('instance')
        if obj:
            initial = [i for i in obj.my_choices.split(',')]
            self.initial['my_choices'] = initial

    def clean_lead_fields(self):
        return ','.join(self.cleaned_data.get('my_choices', []))
```

in `admin.py`

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```